# PHP - SAVE select option value AFTER submission

Tags: php, mysql

I have a drop down menu which lists the associated 'IDs' from the mysql database:

```
<fieldset>
<legend><strong>Change ID:</strong></legend>
<?php
$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$databaseName = "change_management";

$connect = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $databaseName);
$query3 = "SELECT `change_id` FROM `change_request_tbl` WHERE (approval_disposition LIKE 'Requires Editing')";
$result3 = mysqli_query($connect,$query3);
?>

<select required name="change_id">
<option value="">Please specify...
<?php
while ($roww = mysqli_fetch_array($result3))
{
echo "<option value='".$roww['change_id']."'>".$roww['change_id']."</option>";
}
?>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="get" value="Get Details" class="btn">
</fieldset><br><br><br>
```

When the user clicks "Get Details" the dropdown reverts back to "Please specify". I have found many examples of how to save the value after submission, but none seem to be applicable to my code as I am fetching values from the database.
Is there anyway to save the last inputted values in this current format?

Comment: do you need to update it.. specify your question

Comment: When a user clicks "Get details", the value they selected in the change id input should still be there when the details of that change id are echoed

Comment: you don't have any form then why you have submit button?

Comment: i do have a form, I just havent included it in the code as i didnt think it is needed for this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the user submits the form, the form value `change_id` has the value you're looking for.  So when populating your `option` elements you can check if any of them match what was submitted and set it to be selected.  Something like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['change_id']) && $roww['change_id'] == $_POST['change_id']) {
    echo "<option selected value='".$roww['change_id']."'>".$roww['change_id']."</option>";
} else {
    echo "<option value='".$roww['change_id']."'>".$roww['change_id']."</option>";
}
```

Or if you want it all on one line (using the ternary conditional operator):

```
echo "<option ".((isset($_POST['change_id']) && $roww['change_id'] == $_POST['change_id']) ? "selected" : "")." value='".$roww['change_id']."'>".$roww['change_id']."</option>";
```